# Float notification bar over window contents

Tags: wpf, xaml, position

I'd like to display notifications in a bar across the top of my window. I'm planning to have the element appear when there's a notification, then fade out. If I were doing a web page, it would be something like this:

```
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom-style: solid 1px #444;
}
```

then animate either the height or the opacity.

I'm only going to show it for a short period of time so want it to occlude contents rather than move it aside

How in a a WPF app can I dock to the top of an element and float over the contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a existing XAML window design as

```
<Window x:Class=.....>
  <Grid Name="Content" .....>

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

extend it by surrounding the existing content by another Grid and insert your 'fixed' element AFTER the original content inside the wrapping Grid:

```
<Window.....>
  <Grid Name="Wrapper">
    <Grid Name="Content" .....>

    </Grid>

    <Label Name="Static" Height="40" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 3" 
      Background="#40FFFF00" BorderBrush="Gray" Content="Hello" />

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Label is just an example. As it is rendered after your content it is rendered on top. You have to find your way to put it on the right position.

Of course there are several other possibilities to solve your problem; this is just one.

Comment: To clarify, the first elements encountered in parsing the xaml are rendered first? I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Yes the order is important. And a grid is an easy possibility to render the elements in the same area.

Comment: You will see the effect when you swap the two elements.

Comment: I don't think this does quite what I want... I want a notification bar (like when firefox asks to remember a password). I don't want to obscure the main UI, just float a bar at the top of the window.

Comment: So you can either set `VerticalAlignment="Top"` for the label then it will be on the top but still obscure the other content. Or - to prevent the UI to be obscured at all - use a StackPanel as first child element of your Window and put your Label - or notification bar - as first element in the StackPanel. But that would not behave as a fixed element in CSS because - yes - it obscures the UI.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks very much